# efficient replacing of certain diagonal parts of array/matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, finite-element-method, sparse-arrays

in writing some code for FEM i need an efficient way to replace parts of the diagonal of a sparse array. Certain positions in the diagonal of the array (given in a list) should be changed to "1".

An example would be:

```
mat = RandomInteger[3, {10, 10}];
replacelist = {{1, 1}, {3, 3}, {7, 7}, {10, 10}};
ReplacePart[mat, replacelist -> 999] // MatrixForm
(*
999 0   2   1   1   3   2   3   2   1
1   2   0   3   1   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   999 0   2   0   2   3   3   2
1   2   1   1   0   0   3   0   0   1
3   3   2   3   1   1   0   3   1   1
1   2   1   3   0   2   3   1   0   3
2   2   3   1   2   1   999 0   3   3
0   0   1   2   2   1   2   3   3   1
3   1   3   1   2   3   2   3   2   2
2   1   1   0   2   2   0   0   2   999
*)
```

This works, but it is way to slow, since I assume it is done elementwise. It has to be orders of magnitude faster. My skills in using pure functions is unfortunately limited, but I guess there is some clever way to do it with those. Also I have to construct a list first (replacelist) containing all positions twice as row and column for which I guess is a more elegant way possible.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I gave a presentation on this subject a few years back. You can find efficient matrix assembly and modification codes in the talk [Applications of Numerical Computation](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7549/).

Answer (score 4):

This should work with arbitrary lists `replacelist` and `valuelist`.

```
A = SparseArrya[mat];
A += SparseArray[
    replacelist -> Subtract[valuelist, Extract[A, replacelist]], 
    Dimensions[A]
   ]
```

Packaged into a function, this could look like this:

```
Inject[A_SparseArray, replacelist_ -> valuelist_]:= A + SparseArray[
    replacelist -> Subtract[valuelist, Extract[A, replacelist]], 
    Dimensions[A]
   ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I just did a little check and was surprised to see how slow `ReplacePart` really is. I guess that you'll want to use `Part` assignment here since it's really efficient (e.g., `mat[[1, 1]] = 999`), but I don't know of a way to do `Part` assignment to the diagonal at once. However, you can easily do it by `Scan`ning over the elements you want to assign or using `Do`.

```
mat = RandomInteger[3, {1000, 1000}];
replacelist = {{1, 1}, {3, 3}, {7, 7}, {10, 10}};
RepeatedTiming[ReplacePart[mat, replacelist -> 999];]
RepeatedTiming[
 Scan[Function[mat[[#, #]] = 999], replacelist[[All, 1]]];]
RepeatedTiming[Do[mat[[i, i]] = 999, {i, replacelist[[All, 1]]}];]
```

As you can see, it's much faster than `ReplacePart`, even if the elements are done one at a time. The difference is that in `Part` assignment the matrix `mat` does not have to be copied over while `ReplacePart` will create a new copy of the matrix internally.

Comment: Setting single entries of a `SparseArray` with `Part` is also very, very slow.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that `SparseArrays` don't work well with `Part` assignment. Good to know.

Comment: Yeah, the reason is that (in the worst case), the sparsity pattern (internally, that is `A["ColumnIndices"]` and `A["RowPointers"]`) have to be recomputed after each assignment. Best strategy is to manipulate as many entries as possible at once, like setting whole rowa, colums, or rectangular subarrays in one go.

Comment: So just to make sure I never missed anything: I know you can assign to whole rows, columns or blocks at a time, but I couldn't find a mechanism to assign to arbitrary sub-parts of an array (other than `ReplacePart`, which isn't doesn't do in-place assignment). Kind of like the reverse of `Extract`. I take it that WL doesn't have anything for that?

Comment: None that I know of... Good point to phrase it as the reverse of `Extract`! Wouldn't that be called `Inject`?